# Enable datetime selection in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to ruby on rails. I want to display my date format as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. On using `calendar_date_select` method with `:time=>true` in my view, I am able to display the format as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM`. Is there any method which could overwrite the current diplaying format to the format I need?

Comment: Do you mean the [calendar_date_select gem](https://github.com/timcharper/calendar_date_select)?  I don't think this has much current support.  Have you considered a Javascript date picker?  There are many good options out there.

Comment: yes, the calendar_date_select gem. Would you suggest using the JQuery datapicker instead of the ruby gem?

Comment: I would @Anil.  Before I use any gem, I always go to https://rubygems.org/ and look at the pattern of downloads.  Plus I check out the github page for the gem.  This gem seems to have fallen out of use somewhat... doesn't mean you can't make it work, but it may impact the amount of support you can get.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'strftime' method on dates to get any format you desire.

Ex.

```
time = Time.now
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p')    #This gives 2015-07-15 08:28:38 PM
```